# How to update the URL with mouseScroll (ScrollMagic)?

Tags: javascript, scroll, fullpage.js, html5-history, scrollmagic

How can I update dynamically the URL with mouse scroll (and maybe touch) using [ScrollMagic.js](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/index.html)?

I have the rows (blocks) with 100vh for desktop.

On every page I will have 5-25 rows (I don't know how much, because user can 5 or 9 or 22 ).

I know how to make anchors for every block by using  [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

But I need something like that:
http://www.collectif-yay.com/ or http://kosmos.one/3/

I know that this effect was made with **HTML5 History API**. And I find few articles how to make it with event click, but can't find anything how to make it with scroll, especially with ScrollMagic.js

[here](https://mega.nz/#!1S5i2bYL!P2J9vT4t67UsLOHR8He_GO8rAqWtDKfAXlxE5vSbNjM) is local version with fullPage.js (I want to make it with ScrollMagic.

I look forward to being of your help.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: [here is local version](https://mega.nz/#!1S5i2bYL!P2J9vT4t67UsLOHR8He_GO8rAqWtDKfAXlxE5vSbNjM) with fullPage.js (I want to make it with ScrollMagic.

Comment: Why scrollmagic instead of fullPage.js?

Comment: Hi, @Alvaro. Honestly, there is no difference what to use. I add 'ScrollMagic' to the title only because I know how to make interesting animation with it and GSAP.
But if you could help me or make some article in docs how to use HTML5 History API and fullPage.js (on scroll) I would be very appreciate